# Netbeans "unshelve changes" not using internal conflict resolver?

Tags: netbeans

Normally (or by default) when there is a conflict between files in Netbeans you have the option to use its internal conflict resolver, which is an excellent interface for comparing two files and moving and confirming changes.

The Netbeans "shelving" feature is also really cool, it makes putting uncommitted changes aside to work on other issues a breeze, as opposed to going through the process of cloning/pulling/etc. every time you want to temporarily put aside working changes and do something else.

The problem is when you unshelf changes, and Netbeans can't 100% merge the unshelf changes and the new changes, it will simply prompt something along the lines of "could only partially unshelf changes" and that's it. I was really hoping it would prompt the conflict resolver to allow you to easily merge changes. =(

Anyone know if I'm maybe just missing it? Or can I force the conflict resolver using the .patch file shelving changes creates?